# Error 533 in Active Directory LDAP

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to configure Active Directory (AD LDS) for use with my application. I am using ForeignJNDIProvider in Weblogic app server to configure the settings for AD. From my Java based application, I do a lookup on InitialContext as shown below:

```
InitialContext iCtx = new InitialContext();
DirContext dir = (DirContext) iCtx.lookup(<JNDI name>);
```

The second code line above fails with the following error:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 533, v1db1 ]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3067)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3013)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2815)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2729)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:296)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ForeignOpaqueReference.getReferent(ForeignOpaqueReference.java:70)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLNamingManager.getObjectInstance(WLNamingManager.java:96)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.resolveObject(ServerNamingNode.java:377)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.resolveObject(BasicNamingNode.java:856)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:209)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
```

I tried looking up what error 533 in AD meant. The only answer I got was that it meant "Account Disabled". I am not sure this is the case. How can I fix this?

Comment: I just looked up error code 49 (from the stack trace) and found a link here: http://forums.devshed.com/ldap-programming-76/javax-naming-authenticationexception-ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid--121363.html.

I suggest testing LDAP related queries, connections, etc in apache's directory studio (I use it actively): http://directory.apache.org/studio/

Comment: Hi, apache's directory studio looks really cool, but it does not show up directory entries under my DN for AD LDS (which I can see using ADSI Edit). Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Got it...solved the problem by changing the value for attribute msDS-UserAccountDisabled to false. AD accounts when created are disabled by default.
Resource: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725934

Answer (score 3):

For me, the error was in the attribute "userAccountControl".  I had to change it from 546 (ACCOUNTDISABLE | PASSWD_NOTREQD | NORMAL_ACCOUNT) to 512 (NORMAL_ACCOUNT). Also see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144/de